# Are there any StackExchange.Redis example projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

We are thinking of implementing Redis to optimise our webapplications retrieval of custom text descriptions and labels for pages.

We want to use StackExchange.Redis. Are there any example projects or Walkthroughs which would help to understand the project easier?

Comment: I just jumped on the StackExchange.Redis bandwagon as well (having previous good experience with Booksleeve). For now, I just click on the markdown files [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found useful example of using redis StackExchange client here:
[Object Persistence in C# - Part 5 - Redis Provider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWSudwCQur0)

the source code is on [github](https://github.com/ThomasJaeger/ObjectPersistence/tree/2014_12_17)

Answer (score 8):

I use the test project as examples. https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/StackExchange.Redis.Tests

it is pretty good.